# Splash video for 64-bit Raspian (alternative to omxplayer)

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer, 64-bit

I have RPi Zero 2 with 64-bit Bullseye installed. I am using it for a kiosk application. I want to play an intro (splash video) during boot.

The tutorials I read use omxplayer. But when I run the command `sudo apt-get install omxplayer`, the package is not installed, giving the error `"Package 'omxplayer' has no installation candidate"`. When I visit the [omxplayer github page](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer) I see that it is deprecated and also does not support 64-bit.

In this case, I have to switch to a 32-bit operating system to use omxplayer. But I will be using an deprecated app.

Is there any alternative other than omxplayer for splash video? If yes, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome. Search online "linux framebuffer video player" and you should find some things.  I can't say personally if any of them work, but enough people seem to vouch for `mplayer` and `mpv` (the latter may be a fork of the former), albeit I did not see mention of the raspberry pi (but I only skimmed around for two minutes).

Comment: Some solutions may be incompatible even in different raspian versions. So I didn't try to apply the standard linux splash solution to raspberry. (I'm not a good linux user.) Still, it's worth a try. I'll post if I find a solution.